# Characters present in Task Token Generated by Step Function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions, serverless-framework-step-functions

I am using the callback feature of Step Function where I get a Task Token generated internally by step function in my context object.

The link I referred to:- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-to-resource.html#connect-wait-example

Here in example they have given the example of token as :-  "Token": "h7XRiCdLtd/83p1E0dMccoxlzFhglsdkzpK9mBVKZsp7d9yrT1W"

I was interested in knowing which all characters does this token contain? Like here I can see "slash" as well. There is no documentation regarding this as well.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR Most likely only the [characters supported by `base64`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

---

I don't believe there is any official AWS documentation explicitly stating the allowed character set in the TaskToken, only that the maximum length is 1024.

I poked around within my own account and noticed that the length of the `$$.TaskToken` is dependent on the name given to the step-function execution  (at least for the eventbridge integration).

The documentation does however state the following:

> You must pass task tokens from principals within the same AWS account. The tokens won't work if you send them from principals in a different AWS account.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-to-resource.html#connect-wait-token

My assumption based on the previous two observations is that the token is a base64 encoded HMAC digest similar to the [AWS Signature V4 signing process](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/signature-version-4.html)

Confirming via an AWS Support case asking if they can provide you with this info is advised if you're needing it for production workloads though.